# Finding a given word in MS Powerpoint by Aspose

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

I am trying to check a MS Powerpoint is contain a given word or not by Aspose, but it does not work.

This is my class which is responsible to check the ppt file:

```
public class FindContentOfPpt
{
    private static bool IsParagraphContain(IParagraph paragraph, string content)
    {
        return paragraph.Portions.Any(port => port.Text.Contains(content));
    }

    private static bool IsTextBoxContain(ITextFrame textBox, string content)
    {
        return textBox.Paragraphs.Any(para => IsParagraphContain(para, content));
    }

    private static bool IsSlideContain(ISlide slide, string content)
    {
        var allTextBoxes = SlideUtil.GetAllTextBoxes(slide);
        return allTextBoxes.Any(textBox => IsTextBoxContain(textBox, content));
    }

    public bool IsContain(string filePath, string content)
    {
        var pres = new Presentation(filePath);

        return pres.Slides.Any(slide => IsSlideContain(slide, content));
    }
}
```

And I call it to check a given word:

```
var isContain = new FindContentOfPpt().IsContain("Find and Replace.pptx", "Presentation");
```

The isContain is always false although my ppt file contain a text box with content:"This is Presentation". I already debugged, and the class can open the ppt file, but the textbox value is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it because of 'truncated due to evaluation version limitation.". When you don't have license, it will limited to almost features of Aspose. You can request a trial version for full testing.

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved it. The problem came from "text has been truncated due to evaluation version limitation.". That 's mean I did not use valid license, and all text values in all text boxes was truncated.

Solution: I have requested a trial license, added it to my project:

```
Aspose.Slides.License license = new Aspose.Slides.License();
license.SetLicense("my license file");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nhan Phan,

When you use API without license, it impose limitation on all text extraction. When you use license then API does not limit you to use any feature.